# Constraints not applying inside inputView to pickerView

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am trying to center my `UIPickerView` inside a `view` which is inside `inputView` - looks like this

- inputView

  - myView

    - UIPickerView

The problem is that no matter what constraints I use it just doesn't change anything.

What I've tried so far:

```
let centerXConstraint = myPickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerXAnchor)
let centerYConstraint = myPickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerYAnchor)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])
```

And also the old way:

```
let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myPickerView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myPickerView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])
```

And also like this:

```
myPickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor).isActive = true
myPickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
myPickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myPickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
```

The output is like this(not in center) no matter what I do. I can even remove those constraints, the output is the same:

[image]

If I put breakpoint to NSLayoutContraint activation line, it stops there. If I opt-out the `myView`, the `myPickerView` is centered by default inside `inputView` but I need the `myView` there to have more customization.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't work with picker views much, but have you checked the actual width of it? Maybe it *is* centered with some padding to the right.

Comment: A quick way to check is to give `inputView and `myView` different backgroundColors, and if needed, print their frames - just be sure for the frame check to do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. I'm not saying this is your issue, just throwing it out there - your constraints look good to me.

Comment: @dfd it is so weird. I just tried to apply width to my pickerView equal to `self.view.frame.size.width` and it is correctly there. But why those constraints didn't do the trick? If I set the width then it just stretches it out.

Comment: I have no idea. I could see setting a height might be an issue due to "intrinsic size" but I'd have thought width would work with a picker. Maybe that's why I've shied away from them. :-)

Comment: @dfd that's why I didn't want to set the width but at least it is better than the last output I got. Thank you for your help - without your comment I wouldn't even have tried it. But I think the issue is with the inputView. It has by default some kind of content hugging I think and won't let you to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting the pickerView width equal to the superview width like this: `myPickerView.frame.size.widt = self.view.frame.size.width`. It is not the solution I would like but I couldn't find any other solution for that specific issue.

I think that Apple won't let you do do things with components like `inputView` since it is pretty much keyboard and they do not let you change anything that is related to that. And also I think that the `inputView` has some get-only properties and default content hugging.